# Atomically download a CVS file in .NET core

Tags: file, .net-core, model-view-controller, dynamic, razor-pages

I am making a dynamic CVS report file in my controller in the format of StringBuilder. I have tried this code to return the file:

public async Task GetCvsAsync(....)
{
....
//making the file

```
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            StreamWriter objstreamwriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
            objstreamwriter.Write(res.ToString());
            objstreamwriter.Flush();
            objstreamwriter.Close();
            return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/octet-stream", "test.csv");
        }

    }
```

it makes the correct result but in the console response header (nothing happens in the front) like this:
[image]

if I right-click on the console and click open in a new tab, it will start to download the file. I have tried this way as well:

```
var f = File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(res.ToString()), "text/csv", "authors.csv");
return f;
```

res is in the type of StringBuilder.

I want to download automatically begins after the file is ready, I have no idea what should I do.

note:
this action called by a href tag onClick event on my razor page:

```
function cvs(meID, oID, tID) {
        $.get("/Dashboard/GetCVS?meID=" + meID
            + "&oID=" + oID+ "&tID=" + tID);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear to me specifically what behavior you're describing.  When you right click on the link and open in a new tab, it downloads the file as expected?  But when you click on the link normally it doesn't?  What does it do instead?

Comment: I didn't say that I right-click on the link, I said when I right-click on the console response (in the picture). in fact, nothing happening in the front (just if I check the console I can see this result ). is it clear now?

Comment: Ah, it looks like the issue is that you're trying to download a file via AJAX, but the client-side code isn't doing anything with the response.  Does this answer your question? [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't solve my problem with jquery I just change my code to direct calling my action instead of ajax call and my problem solved!